# delete an array in list array in laravel session

Tags: php, laravel

I have a session to save cart info in laravel like this:

```
$item = [
          'id' => 1,
          'product_id' => 11
        ];

$item2 = [
          'id' => 2,
          'product_id' => 22
        ];
        \Session::push('cart', $item); 
        \Session::push('cart', $item2);
```

Now I want delete an Item in array for `$id=1`:

```
foreach(\Session::get('cart') as $cart)
{
    if($id==$cart['id'])
    {
       echo 'done';
       \Session::forget('cart.' . $i);
    }
    $i++;
}
```

It print `done` but it can not delete that item in list.

what is my wrong?

also I try `\Session::pull('card.id', $id);`

**EDIT**

with `dd(\Session::get('cart'))`

```
array:4 [▼
  2 => array:5 [▼
    "id" => 1
    "product_id" => "11"
  ]
  3 => array:5 [▶]
  4 => array:5 [▶]
  5 => array:5 [▶]
]
```

So I try change the code to this:

```
foreach(\Session::get('cart') as $key->$cart)
{
    if($id==$cart['id'])
    {
       \Session::forget('cart.' . $key);
    }
}
```

But It can not delete too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that `cart.{$id}` is not a session key, as you're only explicitly setting `cart`, which is an `array`. This should work for you instead:

```
$id = 1; // set from request, etc.
$cartSession = session()->get("cart");
foreach($cartSession AS $index => $cart){
  if($index == $id){
    unset($cartSession[$index]);
  }
}
session()->put("cart", $cartSession);
```

Essentially, you pull the session to a variable (`array`), loop that and `unset` where `$index` matches `$id`, then set the remaining `array` back as `"cart"`.

Note: I'm using `session()` instead of `\Session`, which is just Facade vs global function; shouldn't make a difference on which you use, unless below a certain Laravel version (< 5.0 I believe)

Comment: with change to this: `if($id==$cart['id'])`, your code works. thanks.

Comment: Sorry; disappeared there (software update), was gonna say I probably missed the comparison requirement. But regardless, glad I could help!